# TypeError: Error while trying multer module

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs, multer

Good day geniuses, I am new in backend technology. I'm building a project that uploads files and text to my database but I'm getting an error message. I'm using nodejs and mongoDB as my database.
I will be looking forward to advices here. Thanks

Below is my server code.

```
const express = require('express');
const {default:mongoose} = require('mongoose');
const multer = require('multer');
const Storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: 'uploads',
    filename:(req, file, cb)=> {
        const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9)
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    },
})    
const upload = multer({
    storage:Storage
}).single('image')
const Blog = require('./models/blog.js');
    
mongoose
    .connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/filesUpload") 
    .then(()=>{console.log('Mongo server has started')})
    .catch(()=>{console.log('Connection to Mongo Failed')})

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
app.set('views engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", async (req, res)=>{
    const blogs = await Blog.find()
    res.render('index.ejs', {title: 'HOME', blogs})    
})

app.post("/blogs/create", (req, res)=>{    
    upload = (req, res, (err)=>{
        if (err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        else{    
            const blog = new Blog({
                title: req.body.title,
                snippet: req.body.snippet,
                body: req.body.body,
                image: {
                    date: req.file.filename,
                    contentType: "image/jpg"
                }
            });    
            blog.save().then(()=>{
                res.redirect('/')
            }).catch((err)=>{
                console.log(err)
            }) 
        }
    })
})    

app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log('Server is currently running')
})
```

below is the error message I get when I click the post request:

```
TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
    at C:\Users\go\Desktop\not\files\app.js:53:12
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\go\Desktop\not\files\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\go\Desktop\not\files\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\go\Desktop\not\files\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\go\Desktop\not\files\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\go\Desktop\not\files\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\go\Desktop\not\files\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (C:\Users\go\Desktop\not\files\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at jsonParser (C:\Users\go\Desktop\not\files\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:119:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\go\Desktop\not\files\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: Maybe a typo. `upload = (req, res, (err)=>{}`, `upload` is declared using the `const` keyword.

Comment: I don't understand you. Should I use the keyword there?

Comment: You wrote `const upload = multer({...})` near the top of your file. In your `app.post` you then wrote `upload = (req, res, (err)=>{...})`. Because there was no keyword (`let` or `const`) used to scope the variable to the block or function it means you want to reach out of that `app.post` function and use the variable already declared as `upload`...well that's already been declared as a `const` and can't be changed through reassignment.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are some errors in your code that are causing the issue. Here's a reformatted version of your code with the corrections:

```js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path'); // Add this for path handling
const Storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, 'uploads'); // Corrected the destination path
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9);
    cb(null, uniqueSuffix + path.extname(file.originalname)); // Append the extension
  },
});
const upload = multer({
  storage: Storage,
}).single('image');
const Blog = require('./models/blog.js');

mongoose
  .connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/filesUpload', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Mongo server has started');
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log('Connection to Mongo Failed');
  });

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // Add { extended: true }
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const blogs = await Blog.find();
  res.render('index.ejs', { title: 'HOME', blogs });
});

app.post('/blogs/create', (req, res) => {
  upload(req, res, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      const blog = new Blog({
        title: req.body.title,
        snippet: req.body.snippet,
        body: req.body.body,
        image: {
          date: req.file.filename,
          contentType: 'image/jpg',
        },
      });
      blog
        .save()
        .then(() => {
          res.redirect('/');
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server is currently running');
});
```

Changes and corrections made to the code:

1. Added path module to handle file extensions properly.
2. Fixed the destination path in the Storage configuration.
3. Changed `app.set('views engine', 'ejs')` to `app.set('view engine', 'ejs')`.
4. Added `{ extended: true }` in `express.urlencoded()` middleware.
5. Changed the reassignment of the upload variable to `upload(req, res, ...)` to properly call the middleware.